# Можно ли и как, вызвать android клавиатуру у пользователя telegram бота?

Tags: python, android, telegram-bot, aiogram

Пытаюсь написать telegram бота, и мне нужно чтоб при некоторых настройках выпадала android числовая клавиатура, чтобы ввести число. Иногда необходимо вызвать клавиатуру на английской раскладке иногда на русской. Я нашёл только inline и rplay kyboard, но это заготовленные сообщения которые давно уже у меня есть.

Comment: Я очень сомневаюсь, что у библиотеки aiogram имеется функционал, который может взаимодействовать с OS.
Вы можете явно попросить у пользователя ввести какое-то число, после чего обработать его.
Сами представьте, как функционал aiogram может реализовывать Android клавиатуру, если Telegram используется не только на Android, а ещё и на IOS, Windows и т.д.